# Node single property variable not working?

Tags: python, compositing-nodes, drivers

I am making a node group,and for this node group I want to make an input connected to a value in the bokeh image node,but unfortunately the node has no inputs so I had to see another way to make an input (If you know how to do this please tell me),so what I did is adding a math node and add a driver to the input in the bokeh node with the variable the 1st input in the multiply node (math) while the 2nd input equal 1,but when I add a variable to the driver (single property variable) and select the scene and copy the RNA of the 1st value in the multiply node `nodes["Math"].inputs[0].default_value` it didn't work and value is not updated and it is marked in red as you see here
[image]

so how can I get it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `node_tree.nodes["Math"].inputs[0].default_value`

When you open Outliner and select Datablocks in the header you can see and list the data structure.

Comment: this works fine,but as soon as I make a group of the node tree and make the input is the variable everything stopped working,I tried to correct the RNA but it didn't work too,how can I fix that?and thanks

Comment: Use the Outliner its all there. Its probably `node_tree.nodes['Group'].node_tree.nodes['Math'].inputs[0].default_value` where the 'Group' is name of your node group and 'Math' node is inside that group

Comment: but the math input has gone because it is now one of the inputs in the node group,I tried to take the path of the input by "node_groups["Google material design"].inputs[0].default_value" but this didn't work

Comment: Ok give the .blend or a screenshot of nodes, Ill might be able to help better when I see the structure..

Comment: here is the blend file http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33366
I have replaced the the math node with a transform node so I can do a lot of inputs in one node.

Comment: Looks like inside groups drivers don't update well and don't work this way. It's probably a limitation.